# Git Bash - find words in a file (or string) matching specified sub-string

Tags: bash, cpu-word

cmd: cat test.txt | grep pin
results: prints all lines containing pin

I want to now only grep for words containing pin.
What is the command to so that?

Thanks!

All, thank you for your comments.
I am using the Git Bash (version 1.9.4).
The grep in this shell do not have the -o option.
There is a -w option.
I tried: grep -w 'pin' test.txt 
but it returns nothing.

Anyone using Git Bash to solve this issue?

Thank you all.

Comment: You can do `grep -o` to only print the matching part of a line.

Comment: `grep -o '\w*pin\w*' test.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*pin[^[:blank:]]*' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is called `test.txt`, you can do:

`grep -o '\S*pin\S*' test.txt`

The `-o` flag will print only the matching words on the line, as opposed to the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -w option.

```
$ cat test
pin
PIN
somepin
aping
spinx
$ grep pin test
pin
somepin
aping
spinx
$ grep -w pin test
pin
$
```